# how to remove 'disabled' from input if previous input has value

Tags: jquery, html, forms, disabled-input

I've been trying some experimentation with jQuery, basically it's not working, this is my HTML:

```
<input class="span4" value="" id="dpd1" type="text"> <!-- Input that needs value -->
<input class="span4" value="" id="dpd2" type="text" disabled> <!-- Input which needs 'enabled' -->
```

and here's what I'm trying with jquery:

```
$('#dpd2').click( function () {
    var value = $('#dpd1').val();
    if( value.length > 0 ){
    $("#dpd2").prop('disabled', disabled); }
    });
```

probably shouldn't be trying to have all this happen on click, but I haven't really done anything like this in jQuery before, so not sure what way is best for this type of situation.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I picked the answer which best highlighted the shortest and effective way for me to achieve the outcome I wanted. But there are some other great answers there too! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to do it in the `blur` of first textbox,

```
$('#dpd1').blur(function () {
    $("#dpd2").prop('disabled', !$.trim($('#dpd1').val()).length);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P2vV2/)

[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) takes a boolean. And when you set your textbox to disabled initially you can no longer click on it. hence use `blur` to perform the action once you focus out of the first textbox.Use `$.trim()` to remove the whitespaces from ends of the textbox value

Comment: Very nice, I like the size of this. Very informative. If I'm right you are using the `!$('#dpd1').val().length` to bring a true or false outcome?

Comment: Yes length if 0 means,  !0 is true or else false

Comment: Thanks! You've just opened up a new chapter for me. Something I had never noticed due to naivety.

Answer (score 3):

Use boolean values to disable / enable properties with `prop()` :

```
$('#dpd1').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#dpd2').prop('disabled', this.value.length < 1); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Zah/)

Comment: the one you just deleted... :rolleyes:

Comment: @Shomz that is why i deleted

Comment: @Shomz - Strangely enough Ankit commented on my error before he/she fixed the same error in his/her own answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I complained... typical lame behaviour. I like your final answer (although it's similar to mine), btw. +1

Comment: @Shomz yes i commented on after editing mine but deleted the answer because i was confused to choose how to show the desired effect whether attach an event to #dp1 or do something else.So it is not a lame behavior

Comment: @adeneo, there is one advantage of using `change` instead of `keyup` - when pasting the value into the box, but I guess it's a minor thing.

Comment: @Shomz - preferably the `input` event should be used I think, but that's only supported in newer browsers, but does include paste, change, keys etc.

Comment: Yup, I think we still need to wait a bit for that one.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, click won't work here, you need to implement [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler, then check whether the value is an empty string, and if not, change the disabled property on the other input.

Something like:

```
$('#dpd1').change(function () {
    $("#dpd2").prop('disabled', $('#dpd1').val() == '');
});
```

Comment: +1 for `change` - I really need to take my head out of PHP once in a while

Comment: Yeah, `change` is *exactly* what's needed here. Like I said, `keyup` and `blur` work as well, but `change` covers every scenario.

Comment: I used @PSL's answer but modified it with `change` as it seems to work better in my situation

Comment: @Ricki sure, whatever works best for the situation. Just don't forget the other options in case you need them in the future.